# Web Form - Form that inserts information into Sharepoint Access App which is located on an SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, forms, sharepoint

I am having an issue creating a Web Form that inserts information into an Access App on my Sharepoint Site. Currently having issues with developing the form and looking for direction, help or anything that will further my progress will be appreciated. This is my first time trying to create a web form. Here are the elements that are surrounding in the development of my the form:

-Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Web

-Sharepoint

-Access App

-Web Form

---

Here is the asp that i created in Microsoft Visual Studio:

---

[image: WebForm]

---

These are the steps that I took in Microsoft Visual Studio to create the SQL Connection

---

Step 1 - Clicked New Connection

---

[image: Step 1]

Clicked Next

---

Step 2 - Inserted SQL Database Information for conection

[image: Step 2]

-Tested Connection and came up successful

Clicked Next

---

Step 3 - The Connection String

---

[image: Step 3]

-This is a picture of the connection string created by previous step

Clicked Next

---

Step 4 - Specify a custom SQL statement or Stored Procedures

---

[image: Step 4]

Clicked Next

---

Step 5 - updated the SELECT Function

---

[image: Step 5]

Clicked on INSERT

---

Step 6 - INSERT

---

[image: Step 6]

-The function above will be inserted by the next two steps

Clicked Query Builder

---

Step 7 - INSERT Query Builder

---

[image: Step 7]

-This is the items that I checked and the string that was built

Clicked Test Query

---

Step 8 - ERROR

[image: Step 8]

Notes: I don't understand the Error

---

Image of Access App

---

[image: Access App]

The image shows the database and Table that I am trying to insert information into.

-Also the Access App is setup for connections from ANY LOCATION and ENABLE READ - WRITE CONNECTION

---

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to sharepoint but it would appear that you don't give the Sql insert statement any values or where to find the values to insert. For example: Values(@TextBox1, @TextBox2, @TextBox3, @TextBox4).

Or in your particular case you ID'd the textbox as "FirstName" so your statement should be Values(@FirstName, @LastName) etc.

or you could hard code it just to make sure it works first and then change to the variable.

One other item is that your connection string information is on your webpage which will be accessible to anyone who presses "source code". You should think about putting it in the web config file so it is inaccessible.

Good Luck

Marc